# Pop_back an element from a vector

Tags: c++

I want to enter a string followed by an integer into two separate vectors, one for the string and one for the integers.

If the entered string already exists in the vector for strings, I want to delete that last string entered.

```
while (std::cin >> tempName >> tempScore)
{
    if (tempName != "NoName" && tempScore != 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
        {
            if (tempName == names[i])
            {
                std::cout << "Error, duplicate name!" << std::endl;
                names.pop_back();
                scores.pop_back();
            }
        }
        names.push_back(tempName);
        scores.push_back(tempScore);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Wrong name and score!" << std::endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

This is a sample output using the above code.

```
Enter a name followed by a score
foo 7
bar 9
foo 3
Error, duplicate name! 
^Z
foo 7
foo 3
Press any key to continue . . .
```

It deletes my previous input of `tempName` and enters the last entered name, which is the duplicate. I tried using `vector.erase` but this gives me a `no instance of overloaded function`.

Comment: Did you [read the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase)? The `erase` method takes an iterator ... like the one you can get by calling `names.find(tempName)` instead of rolling your own loop.

Comment: "*If the entered string already exists in the vector for strings, I want to delete that last string entered.*" What's the problem? Your code seems to be working exactly like this. Also, you may want to use a map for this instead of parallel vectors.

Comment: `pop_back();` will delete the last element from vector not the duplicate one in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Using a map will be more efficient in solving your problem *i.e* logarithmic time complexity. It will also be concise and intuitive.

```
std::map< string, int> mymap;
// your loop starts
mymap[tempName] = tempScore;
// loop ends
```

If the string already is present, the set value statement will replace the value of string.

Answer (score 0):

To erase from a vector use `find` and `erase`

```
vector<string>::const_iterator citr = std::find(names.cbegin(), names.cend(), tempName);
if (citr != names.cend())
{
    names.erase(citr);
}
```

To make your life easier, like @devsaw suggested, use a map so you can lookup more efficiently and remove both your string and integer entry in one call.